# Prevent Resetting of Countdown Timer On Page Refresh - Django & JS

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am working on Django, I wanted to create a countdown timer and once the timer reaches 0 minutes a "Done" button is enabled. On clicking "Done" a user gets points, now I should make sure that user gets points only once. I want to disable the "Done" button for the user after one use.

*HTML*

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="col-3" id="countdown">
        <button id="startClock">Start Timer</button>
    </span>
    <span class="col-1"></span>
    <button class="col-2" id="done">Done!</button>
</div>

<script>
$('#done').hide();

jQuery(function($){
   $('#startClock').on('click', doCount);
});

function doCount(){
    var timer2 = "10:01";
    var interval = setInterval(function() {

  var timer = timer2.split(':');
  //by parsing integer, I avoid all extra string processing
  var minutes = parseInt(timer[0], 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timer[1], 10);
  --seconds;
  minutes = (seconds < 0) ? --minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 0) ? 59 : seconds;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  $('#countdown').html(minutes + ':' + seconds);
  if (minutes < 0)
      clearInterval(interval);
  //check if both minutes and seconds are 0
  if ((seconds <= 0) && (minutes <= 0)){
      clearInterval(interval);
      $('#done').show();
  }

  timer2 = minutes + ':' + seconds;
   }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a variable to track whether the user has clicked on the done button or not.

```
let isDone = false;
isDone = true;
```

You can also use localStorage for this. This way you can access the value even the user refreshes the browser.

Please note that it can be bypassed so make sure that you have some validation on the server side.

**Example:**

```
localStorage.setItem("done", true);
```

Hope this helps!